# Protractor: TypeError: fn is not a function

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumber

I'm encountering the following error when I run my UI tests.  I'm new to Javascript so I've been mostly following example code and I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.  Could someone explain why I'm getting this error and what an appropriate fix would be?

Error:

```
[13:00:19] E/launcher - fn is not a function
[13:00:19] E/launcher - TypeError: fn is not a function
```

Homepage object:

```
Homepage.prototype = Object.create({}, {
    checkInBtn: {
        get: function () {
            return element(by.css('div.checkin.booking-date input'));
        }
    }, datePickerDay: {
        value: function (day) {
            return element(by.cssContainingText('.ui-datepicker-calendar a', day));
        }
    }, selectCheckInDate: {
        value: function (day) {
            return this.checkInBtn.click().then(this.datePickerDay(day).click());
        }
    },
});
module.exports = Homepage;
```

Cucumber-Protractor Stepfile

```
this.When(/^I enter the trip information and search$/, function (table) {
var page = new homepage();
        var checkOutDay = new Date(data["DepartureDate"]).getDate();
        page.selectCheckInDate(checkInDay);
        expect(page.checkInBtn.getText()).to.eventually.have.string(checkInDay);
        });
```

Comment: You are calling `var page = new homepage()`, shouldn't it be a capital H `Homepage()` as your declared in your page objects?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `selectedCheckInDate`

```
Homepage.prototype = Object.create({}, {
    checkInBtn: {
        get: function() {
            return element(by.css('div.checkin.booking-date input'));
        }
    },
    datePickerDay: {
        value: function(day) {
            return element(by.cssContainingText('.ui-datepicker-calendar a', day));
        }
    },
    selectCheckInDate: {
        value: function(day) {
            var self = this;
            this.checkInBtn.click().then(function() {
                self.datePickerDay(day).click();
            });
        }
    }
});
module.exports = Homepage;
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?